# Why is my python code so slow (leetcode)?

Tags: python, algorithm

> Given an array of integers, every element appears twice except for
>   one. Find that single one.
>
> Note:
>       Your algorithm should have a linear runtime complexity. Could you implement it without using extra memory?

```
class Solution:
    # @param {integer[]} nums
    # @return {integer}
    def singleNumber(self, nums):
        prev = []
        for i,j in enumerate(nums):
            if j in prev:
                nums[i] = -j
            else:
                prev.append(j)
        return sum(nums)
```

It's a question from leetcode and actually the one with highest AC rate. However, as my code goes, it tells me Time Limit Exceeded and could not been accepted. Could any one analyze my code including the complexity? Thank you so much.

Upadate:
Thank you all and I have changed the "prev" from a list to a set, which works nicely!

```
class Solution:
    # @param {integer[]} nums
    # @return {integer}
    def singleNumber(self, nums):
        prev = set([])
        for i,j in enumerate(nums):
            if j in prev:
                nums[i] = -j
            else:
                prev.add(j)
        return sum(nums)
```

However I am still looking for solutions that requires no extra memories as the question describes.

Update:
I used another way trying to solve the problem but receives a Time Exceeded again.

```
class Solution:
    # @param {integer[]} nums
    # @return {integer}
    def singleNumber(self, nums):
        for i,j in enumerate(nums):
            if j in set(nums[:i+1]):
                nums[i] = -j
        return sum(nums)
```

Actually I an kinda confused that does the slice like nums[:i+1] create a separate list every loop? So is the creation of list the most time consuming here? I used set instead of list so this may reduce the cost for searching.

Comment: Try using set instead of an array (or simply xor all values together)

Comment: Thank you and that's an idea.

Comment: Try replacing the list `prev` with a set. This should reduce search-complexity from O(n) which makes the whole problem O(n**2) down to O(1).

Comment: Hint: the answer to the final sentence is "yes". You don't need a list or a set, or any other collection that grows in size.

Comment: Hint: you can do an in-place sort over the list without using extra memory

Comment: @Sir_FZ: Yeah but sorting is O(n*log(n)) which is not linear

Comment: Why not anyone is suggesting Xor?

Comment: Are the numbers from [1,n]? If so, you can do it *very, very cleanly*.

Comment: @therealprashant The very first comment did.

Comment: @StefanPochmann my bad sorry

Comment: @therealprashant  the first comment was edited (and xor wasn't in the first version)

Comment: @StefanPochmann  the first comment was edited (and xor wasn't in the first version)

Comment: haha Lol @ericlevieil aka Sherlock

Comment: @EricLevieil It's not visible right now (only says "1 hour ago"), but I'm quite certain therealprashant posted his comment about half an hour after that first comment, and comments are only editable for five minutes, so it was already there when he posted. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Peter's answer is brilliant:

```
def singleNumber(nums):
    unique = 0
    for num in nums:
        unique ^= num
    return unique
```

Comment: Doesn't using a foreach loop in Python require O(n) addition memory?

Comment: @erip: Python foreach loops requires O(n) **time** complexity, not space complexity. So the answer fits perfectly the requirements.

Comment: where is he storing the numbers @erip

Comment: My mistake. I thought Python made a copy of the list behind the scenes, but after reading through the docs, it seems it's not the case.

Comment: 这是按位异或，异或操作符是顺序无关的，所以 A^B^A^C^B=A^A^B^B^C=0^C=C，所以一串异或之后剩下的值就是unpaired。数学和数电还是挺重要的，真不是故意设置壁垒啊。

Answer (score 3):

Xor is the way to go.
Xor of two similar element is 0 and hence all dups will vanish resulting the non repeated element to be present in res.

```
x=[1,1,2,3,2,4,4,5,5]
res=x[0]
for i in xrange(1,len(x)):
    res^=x[i]

print res
```

Comment: This is really bad. Compare to Brent's answer.

Comment: Could you explain me how? Thanks

Comment: How to compare it to Brent's answer? I think the differences are clear. Special treatment of the first number is pointless, and the useless index-looping is very ugly and unpythonic.

Comment: Oh! You are right in this. Thanks I will surely keep this in mind @stefanpochmann

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann procedure vs OO ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative, functional way of writing the XOR-solution:

```
from operator import xor
from functools import reduce # [Note]

def single_number(nums):
    return reduce(xor, nums)
```

Note: in Python 3.x, (which apparently Leetcode doesn't use) you'll need to import the `reduce` function from the `functools` module:

Comment: Oh that's very clean, thank you~~

Comment: Leetcode only has Python 2 :-)

Comment: I tried this, but it's roughly 1.7 times slower for an input of 11 and 2.35 times slower for size 2001

Comment: @tennabey Slower than what?

Comment: @tennabey Functional programming solutions are not necessarily the fastest solutions (though in some cases, like with JVM 8, they often can be, since parallelization across multiple cores can be applied in the background). Performance depends on implementation and other things. This answer was just to show a clean way of writing it.

Comment: @StefanPochmann - slower than the `for` loop solutions. @Shashank - of course, but I'm pretty sure the goal here is efficiency.

Comment: @tennabey I'm pretty sure the goal here is efficiency in the sense of not using quadratic runtime that's too slow to get accepted at leetcode. I got 44ms there with the reduce solution, which is among the fastest Python solutions, and I see an accepted solution with about 850ms. Also, in my own tests, the reduce solution was only up to about 15% slower, depending on size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cython (I used it now the second time, so maybe there is still improvement possible):

Create a file `singleNumber.pyx` with following content:

```
def singleNumber(list nums, int nn):
cdef int i, ii, np
cdef list prev = []

for i in xrange(nn):
    np = len(prev)
    for ii in xrange(np):
        if nums[i] == prev[ii]:
            nums[i] = - prev[ii]
        else:
            prev.append(nums[i])
return sum(nums)
```

Create a file `setup.py` with following content:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize('singleNumber.pyx'),
)
```

Compile it: `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

```
import singleNumber as sn
arr = [i + 1 for i in range(1000)]
%timeit sn.singleNumber(arr,len(arr))
```

Result : `100000 loops, best of 3: 15.4 µs per loop`

Using the `XOR` function gives me: `10000 loops, best of 3: 82.1 µs per loop`

EDIT:

I do get different results if I use the `XOR` solutions compared to the original function !

```
from operator import xor

def singleNumber_xor(nums):
    return reduce(xor, nums)

arr = [i + 1 for i in range(10000)]
singleNumber_xor(arr)
```

Gives me: `10000`

The original function:

```
def singleNumber_orig(nums):
    prev = set([])
    for i,j in enumerate(nums):
        if j in prev:
            nums[i] = -j
        else:
            prev.add(j)
    return sum(nums)

singleNumber_orig(arr)
```

Gives me: `50005000`